# Accessing UITableViewCell subview via tag?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm adding a UIProgressView to table cells as shown:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [videosTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(long)videoIndex inSection:0]];
UIProgressView *prg =[[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
prg.tag = (long)videoIndex + 1000;
[cell addSubview:prg];
```

I'm later (in AppDelegate.m) trying to access this progress bar using the following:

```
UITableView *table = (UITableView *)[self.videosTableController.view viewWithTag:8888];
UITableViewCell *cell = [table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
UIProgressView *progressBar = (UIProgressView *)[cell viewWithTag:index+1000];
return progressBar; //this always is nil.....
```

What's going on?  I've verified that `table` and `cell` are not returning nil, but the UIProgressView does not seem to be in the cell.  I've looped through the cell's subviews, but cannot see the progress bar.

Comment: Are you sure `videoIndex` and `index` are the same?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a cell recycling issue? I would also suggest that you are using an incorrect pattern. Rather than trying to set and change the cell directly; it's a better idea to make changes to the model objects that the cell is displaying properties for and let the cell pick up changes from there. Looking at your description - when you say you are trying to access the cell in the _AppDelegate_ - that in itself is a code smell to me.

Comment: @Slayter - Yes, I've verified they're the same.

Comment: @Anorak - Using AppDelegate for a background-running NSURLSessionDownloadTask seems to be an accepted practice.... As for the cell recycling issue, I'm not sure about that.  Could you be more specific?  I only have two cells in the table.

Comment: @croceldon you should set `prg.tag = (long)videoIndex + 1000;` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is because `[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` may return a new cell instance from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in some cases.

Comment: @croceldon on a side note, view tags are super unsafe and not the best approach for what appears to be the behavior you need

Comment: @BartekChlebek  I don't want a progress view in every cell, so I'm not using the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.  How else would I find a specific view if I didn't use tags?

Comment: @croceldon you should distinguish what kind of cell (with progress or without) you need inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, create an appropriate one, configure it and return.

Comment: If cell at indexpath is not visible you can't find your progress.

Comment: @croceldon for example your `videosTableController` could expose a readonly property with the `tableView`, and not be accessed via `tag`.

Comment: @Yusufterzi you are correct, but croceldon mentioned that "I've verified that table and cell are not returning nil" so that appears not be the case here.

Comment: @croceldon MVC. The AppDelegate shouldn't be messing about with the cells displayed in a table view. It should update the model and let the table view controller deal with configuring the cells.

Comment: Maybe `UITableViewCell *cell = [videosTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(long)videoIndex inSection:0]];` this is nil. Before adding cell is hidden.

Comment: Ok @BartekChlebek, I see you're right on the best way to handle the UIProgressView creation.  If you'd like to format an answer below, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: @croceldon there you go. Glad I could help :) happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `prg.tag = (long)videoIndex + 1000;`
in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

This is because `[table cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` may return a new cell instance from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in some cases.

So, you should distinguish what kind of cell (with progress or without) you need inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, create an appropriate one, configure it and return.